# using Windows.Services.Maps doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

I'm trying to use a map in a wpf program and use the MapRouteFinder to calculate the driving routes. The problem is, that I need the Windows.Services.Maps in order to do this but I can't find it anywhere. I tried searching for a reasonable alternative but couldn't find one either.
The basing my program strongly on [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/routes-and-directions).

Comment: You mean your internet search for "WPF Map Control" did not reveal anything useful? E.g. like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/mapcontrol

Comment: Since MapRouteFinder is an UWP class, you may consider writing an UWP app instead of WPF. Take a look at [Display routes and directions on a map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/routes-and-directions).

Comment: You may also want to take a look at https://openrouteservice.org/

Comment: But, I don't want to wirte an UWP App. The rest of my Team is wirting their things in WPF and we have to put it together in the end so thats not really an option. I have to find either the Windows.Services.Maps namespace or a reasonable alternative to calculate routes with directions and stuff.

Comment: Yeah I'm gonna look into the openrouteservice, that looks promising. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at OpenRouteService Directions. It is a a simple REST API returning GeoJSON.

Comment: If you are going to use it in wpf there is already a map. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/wpf-control/hh750210(v=msdn.10)

Answer (score 1):

Windows.Services.Maps is a UWP library, not a WPF library, likely why you can't find it.

In WPF, to geocode or calculate routes, you will need to call the Bing Maps REST services directly. You will likely find the BingMapsRESTToolkit very useful: https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsRESTToolkit

Also note, the Bing Maps WPF SDK is very old and limited in features. For a more advance set of features, you can run the UWP maps SDK in a WPF via a XAML island.

https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2019/04/23/net-core-3-use-uwp-controls-in-wpf-with-xaml-islands/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uWaQi73Adtc